# SSRS reporting - error when I make two IFF statements in one string

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, expression, visibility

I am trying to combine to iff statements for a textbox in the footer of my main report:

```
=IIF(not(ISNOTHING(First(Fields!psa_project_psa_legalentity.Value, "DSMain"))) And First(Fields!psa_project_psa_legalentity.Value, "DSMain") = "M&P Audit B.V.", False, True) 

=IIF(globals!PageNumber = 1, False, True)
```

Separately they function perfectly fine however when I want to merge them for a visibility expression  I get a error everytime I upload the report. These are the things I tried so far:

```
=IIF((not(ISNOTHING(First(Fields!leg_psa_name.Value, "DSMain"))) And First(Fields!leg_psa_name.Value, "DSMain") = "M&P Audit B.V.", False, True)) 
& IIF(globals!PageNumber = 1, False, True)
```

and

```
=IIF(not(ISNOTHING(First(Fields!leg_psa_name.Value, "DSMain"))) And First(Fields!leg_psa_name.Value, "DSMain") = "M&P Audit B.V.", False, True) 
, IIF(globals!PageNumber = 1, False, True)
```

Does anybody have some advice for me how to do it?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest your IIF statements in order to use both of them in the same expression box.

```
example expression: =IIF(IIF(condition1,trueCase1,falseCase1)condition2,trueCase2,falseCase2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just tried this one:

=IIF(IIF(globals!PageNumber = 1, False, True)not(ISNOTHING(First(Fields!leg_psa_name.Value, "DSMain"))) And First(Fields!leg_psa_name.Value, "DSMain") = "Mulderij & Partners B.V.", False, True)

But it unfortunately does not work. Do you spot what I am doing wrong? Do I maybe need to add extra brackets?